# Backend authentication without logging in using PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I have an application that all the radiologists generates their reports by logging into the application. But I does not want user to login with their user id and password. when a user enters url it should not open a login page . I tried returning true when a user enters an URL like below.

```
<?php  if($app->isLoggedIn()) { 

        $title="Temlate post data"; 
        include 'pages/post-data.php'; //This is keep on opening if i disable this showing showing blank page.
        $url = $app->current_url();
        $app->log('visit',$title,$url,$b);
        exit(); 
}

 public function isLoggedIn() 
    {
       if(empty($_SESSION['login']))
       {
          return true; 
       } else { 
         return false;  
   } 
}
```

But above code is allowing user to show only `post-data.php` page. I want him to access all other pages. How do I do default authentication.

Any help would appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean: `if(!empty($_SESSION['login']))` ?

I assumed you're testing to see if the user is logged in. Therefore you want to check whether SESSION contains login information or not.

Comment: if (empty($_SESSION['login'])) {  return false;     } I have added this but user is able to access only one page without login.

Comment: Clear the browser cache and try again. I'm still not sure what you're aiming for..  The problem could be caused by another part of the script..

Comment: if I return true showing empty pages if I return false showing login page..tried clearing browser cache but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try using

> > if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) { return true; }

or just remove the require/include path to the pages you want the public(people with no accounts) to see.